# Авторизация и открытие веб-интерфейса сетевых устройств(роутер) в браузере по умолчанию

Tags: c#, http, авторизация

Как мне из программы отправить http-запрос на роутер или др. сетевое устройство, требующее авторизацию? Вот как-то прочитал в книге по сетевому программированию (ниже код), что можно так. Все хорошо проходит и возвращает web-страницу авторизации, и не более того. Как решить задачу?

```
WebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.0.1/index.cgi#");

request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("login", "password");
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.ASCII);

textBox1.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();
response.Close();
reader.Close();
```

Comment: Авторизуйтесь в браузере и при это отследите какой запрос, с какими данными и в каком формате отправляется. Потом аналогичным образом проделайте в программе, маскируясь под браузер.

Comment: (http://192.168.0.1/index.cgi?v2=y&rq=y&res_json=true&res_config_action=1&res_config_id=104&res_struct_size=1) - это то что он все время отправляет после входа. Что значит маскироваться под браузер? Есть литература на эту тему, скиньте пожалуйста?!@Mr. Modest

Comment: клиент обычно по умолчанию маскируется браузером, если вы сами не меняете User-Agent. По крайней мере так при использовании WebClient и HttpClient. С WebRequest не работал =/

Comment: Ладно, спасибо! Может кто-нибудь еще ответит, а я пока поищу дальше!

Comment: на всякий случай уточните модель роутера, чтобы отвечающим было проще сориентироваться

Comment: Попробуйте отследить заголовки при отправке запросов. Авторизация может прятаться в них. В этом вам может помочь компоненты разработчика, которые встроены в любой браузер. Или же попробуйте использовать программу Fiddler.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, я вот потихоньку начинаю входить в тему. Дело в том, что мне необходимо написать что то универсальное, для любых сетевых устройств. Чтобы поймать запрос с полей login и password, которых отправляет браузер из кода, вставить свои данные и выполнить вход.

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от типа авторизации HTTP authentication или HTTP POST (логин и пароль вводятся в самом веб интерфейсе с использованием форм), ваш код подойдет только для первого случая. Во втором случае лучше воспользоваться отладочным прокси сервером например Fiddler он покажет строку авторизации для POST запроса.